# Compress a dictionary

Tags: javascript, pusher

I'm using [Pusher](http://www.pusher.com) to send a JSON file to my webapp. My problem is that pusher has a size limit of 10Kb on what it can push and my JSON is around 14-20Kb ( 1816 Bytes to by precise ).  So it return an error 413.

Can I compress this dict / JSON and decompress it in javascript in my app? How can I do that? I have look around  but couldn't find anything I could understand  (I'm a beginner) or use.

Sample of the dict I'm sending with pusher. http://pastebin.com/x2jkhqmr

Thanks!

Comment: Your data is not [valid JSON](http://json.org/), it does not `JSON.parse()`. For example, the boolean literals are `true` and `false`, not `True` and `False`, and Python Unicode string literals `u'…'` are not supported in JSON. You need to fix that first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887915/making-json-responses-even-smaller-just-an-idea/7903527#7903527

Comment: if it was a valid json, could I compress it to make it smaller?

Comment: I wrote a gzip compressor in Javascript, and it was abysmally slow. I would not recommend trying to decompress something like this on the client unless absolutely necessary. The overhead for downloading the gzip library would most likely be bigger than any gain you'd get from compressing your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to compress your data, I'd just break it up and send it in multiple parts of less than 10K each.
Compression has a limit, whereas you can send as many chunks of data as needed.

Comment: AFAICS, splitting up *nested* data into chunks of a maximum size is not a trivial computational problem.

Comment: @PointedEars:  ...for very general, arbitrary data, no...in his case though, pretty easy.  He is trying to transfer 13 keys, with a json representation of about 1410 bytes per key (give or take 10 bytes).

Comment: I am afraid you are mistaken. I have run the corrected version of the data through `eval("(" + … + ")")` which shows that it is a rather deeply nested structure. For example, there is a path in the resulting object `obj` that is `obj["37828"].lineUp.Ba.captain`. Can you guarantee that it can always be split up as you suggest?

Comment: I'm not mistaken on how large the json representation for the values of each key is...and the level of nesting is irrelevant (I didn't mention it).  I did say there were 13 keys, and the json representation of each one is very, very close to one another...which it is.

Comment: In the end I decided to go down that route. I have also fix my JSON :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your data was [valid JSON](http://json.org/) (which it is not), you can remove unnecessary whitespace from it, using the equivalent of the following code:

```
data = data.replace(/('(?:[^\\']|\\.)*'|"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*")|\s+/g, "$1");
```

This would reduce those 17'264 characters to 15'141 characters (−12.3%).

Further, you can define a convention for your Web application by which you transmit boolean literals as numbers, say `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`:

```
data = data.replace(
  /('(?:[^\\']|\\.)*'|"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*")|true|false/g,
  function (m, p1) {
    if (p1) return p1;
    return (m === "true") ? "1" : "0";
  });
```

This would reduce the payload by another 2'657 characters (−17.5%).

Removing the unsupported (and in JSON unnecessary) `u'…'` notation shaves off 151 characters from this data already:

```
data = data.replace(/u?('(?:[^\\']|\\.)*'|"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*")/g, "$1");
```

(Python has [escape sequences for Unicode characters](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html), e. g. `\x12\x23…`. If for some reason you would use that, you could reduce the payload by at least 3 characters per escaped character if you decoded it first.  ECMAScript implementations have had built-in Unicode support for more than a decade now.)

Finally, you can transmit string values that are integer numbers less than 2<sup>54</sup>−1 as numbers [without loss of precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format%3a_binary64), removing two characters (pairs of `'` and `"`) per such string value.

Comment: Trying to pack this data tighter, hoping it will squeeze in under 10K is a recipe for failure in the future.  Didn't run your calcs, but assuming it manages to squeeze in under 10K today, as soon as he adds another couple of keys in the future this will break.

Comment: @Gerrat I concur. The communication model of the application needs to be reconsidered, or the library exchanged, for your approach of slicing the payload does not scale well either. This answer shows what is possible with packing and how, so by contrast it does answer the question.

Comment: "For your approach of slicing the payload does not scale well either"?  ~1400 bytes per key...pack 6 keys per transmission...how does that not scale???  Given the mean size of 1414 bytes, and a std dev of 7bytes, sending 6 keys/transmission gives far less than a one in a million chance of every having data that wouldn't work...trying to pack the data tighter your way would break 100% of the time if OP were to add a mere 5 keys!

Comment: @Gerrat Obviously you have not thought this through. The size of a "record" is small *now*.